# Cannot seem to extract more than 88 tweets despite mining for trending keywords

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining

I'm trying to search for around 20,000 tweets using keywords that are currently trending on my timeline.

However, I am only getting about 88 tweets. These are trending keywords in the entire country and it is highly unlikely that there are only 88 tweets available.

Here is my code

```
library(rtweet)
sona_tweets <- search_tweets(
    q = "SONA19 OR SONA2019 OR SONA", 
    n = 25000, 
    type = "popular",
    include_rts = FALSE,
    retryonratelimit = TRUE
)
```

Comment: `rtweet::search_tweets` only returns data from the past 6-9 days. How do you know there are 20,000 tweets matching this criteria? Were they tweeted in recent history?

Comment: its has been a trending topic in the entire country for the last few days. Highly unlikely that there are only 88 tweets

Comment: Have you tried `type="mixed"` -- running with `type="mixed"` I receive over 10,000 results.

Comment: Your solution worked, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `rtweet::search_tweets()`, you should take note of a few limitations and `type` argument.

First, `search_tweets()` only returns data from the past 6-9 days. In addition, to return more than 18,000 statuses in a single call, you must set `retryonlimit = TRUE`.

From the documentation, the `type` argument is defined as:

> Character string specifying which type of search results to return
>   from Twitter's REST API. The current default is type = "recent", other
>   valid types include type = "mixed" and type = "popular".

Therefore to get "everything" from the last 6-9 days, you'll want to use `type = "mixed"`. This means you should change your code to this:

```
library(rtweet)
sona_tweets <- search_tweets(
    q = "SONA19 OR SONA2019 OR SONA", 
    n = 25000, 
    type = "mixed",
    include_rts = FALSE,
    retryonratelimit = TRUE
)
```

and you should return your expected results.